# Author of the question could comment the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, accepted-answer

Author of the question could optionally leave a highlighted / topped comment to accepted answer explaining why did he accepted this one, so the others can quickly see if he got it right or if something is missing. Would it be good idea?

Comment: The name of the OP that marks the signature of the OPs comments is already highlighted. You might want to make clear that you are aware of this and that you mean something else.

Comment: But the OP can leave more comments. There could be special one concluding the question.

Comment: Indeed, you might want to make that clear by editing your question.

Comment: This question is the first time I realized that the question OP's name is highlighted when linked in the comments, as Jan's name is above. Cool.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there needs to be anything special about an "acceptance comment" from the question's OP.An acceptance already presumes that the answer is fully sufficient, and comments can be used to note further. Ideally, you wouldn't accept an answer that was deficient in any significant way.

But acceptance does not imply that the answer is 100% applicable for every possible related issue any reader might be having. The reader is implied to be responsible for assuring the applicability of any answers, guided by acceptance, votes, and comments.

Ultimately, also; I see no reason to give that one comment any more weight than any other comment that might be left.

Comment: Just as a side point though, some users accept the "best" answer even if it isn't 100% sufficient, and even if it hasn't solved their problem. They may have given up, found an answer elsewhere, maybe even started another question, but don't want to tarnish their accept rate. I've been told as much a couple of times, but I've suspected it in far more cases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand And that is the major problem I have with "You should increase your accept rate" comments. Unfortunately, I think such persons likely also would not properly use an "Acceptance Comment", either.

Comment: Yeah I stopped bitching at people about that, though when I see the 20-30% rates (which I haven't seen lately) I'm still likely to say something.

Answer (score 4):

Please, let's not make it more complicated. OPs already have a hard time realizing they *can* comment and end up posting extra answers.

What's the point of this? Note that not all questions are of the [halpthisdoesntworkplzsendtehcodez](/questions/tagged/halpthisdoesntworkplzsendtehcodez) type.. More so on other SE sites, which are not conducive to these types of questions at all.

The acceptance check tells you:

- For a [halpthisdoesntworkplzsendtehcodez](/questions/tagged/halpthisdoesntworkplzsendtehcodez) : The OP got it to work/was told a better method/learned that it is is impossible. A person from the future can decide which by skimming through.
- For a conceptual question : The OP understood what was said.
- For a reference request : The OP was satisfied with the reference.

Basically, *the question was answered*. I went back to some of my older questions just for the heck of it, and I realized that *I could not cook up a valid "acceptance comment" for* any *of them*. Seriously. It may be just me, but I think skimming through the question and/or answer tells you *exactly* why the answer was accepted. Usually you don't even need to do that.

It really doesn't help people from the future much if there is an acceptance comment. If this were implemented we'd get 100% "Thanks! It worked!" and 0% useful stuff. And "It worked!" is pretty implicit if there's a green tick.

And then we'd need a 'flag as not an acceptance comment->convert to normal comment'. Which could easily become pretty heavily used.

Also, we already have this:

[image]